# Is it possible to increase the speed of 2captcha in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, 2captcha

I'm trying to automate this:

1. Fill a form
2. Solve the captcha
3. Get data from results

I thought the best way is to use 2captcha service but the problem is that it takes about 20 seconds to solve the captcha.

The captcha from the form it's just an image with 3-4 digits, I think the form is using (JCaptcha).

This is my Python code, very simple:

```
from twocaptcha import TwoCaptcha

solver = TwoCaptcha('API')

i = 1
while i <= 5:
    try:
        result = solver.normal('dos.png')
        break
    except:
        i+=1

print(i)
print(str(result))
```

Is there a way to increase the speed? I know there are a lot of factors involved like the speed of my machine, but I already have a good Mac and a good internet connexion.

I Google it but not found any relevant information.